# speed up array functions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a simple method that finds prime numbers, puts them in an array and then sums them up. What are some possible steps to speed it up?

```
def prime?(number, array)
  array.each do |x|
    if number % x == 0
      return false
    end
  end
  true
end

def sum_prime(number)
  i = 0
  prime = 1
  output = [2]
  while prime < number
    if prime?(prime, output)
      i += 1
      output << prime if prime != 1
      p prime
    end 
    prime += 2
  end
  output.inject(:+)
end

sum_prime(200000)
```

is `array#each` ok? Can I concatinate differently for faster results?

Comment: Assuming you *must* store the values in an array, `array.inject(:+)` seems to be about as fast as one can do it in ruby. The only other suggestion would be to use a compiled language like C but even there the improvement will probably be negligible.

Comment: It doesn't need to be stored in an array. Would you suggest a hash?

Comment: Compare your results to using the built in Prime class (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html). Then you might know if you can get it faster :)

Comment: For really large sum_prime, you could send request to a faster language.  You could also make a few short cuts, by priming a hash with existing known values and starting from there:  shortCut={100 => sum_prime(100), 1000 => sum_prime(1000), ad-nausum.  Then you can just count from the least value and save your self quite a bit of ram.

Comment: @mr.musicman If it doesn't need to be in an array, then add each value to a `sum += prime` as soon as each `prime` is made available.

Comment: @Matt, that's a good point, and I have thought about that, but I have to iterate over each element of the array in prime? However, if you see another way around that, I'm more than happy to try it.

Comment: If your goal is just to sum primes, you might be better off [downloading a list](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.  It uses others' suggestions:

```
require 'prime'
def sum_prime(limit)
  Prime.each(limit).inject(0) {|sum, num| sum + num}
end
puts sum_prime(200000)
```