# combine methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, methods

In an effort to speed up my program, I'm trying to combine these two methods, but am having the hardest time doing it. Here are the methods:

```
def prime?(number, array)
  array.each do |x|
    if number % x == 0
      return false
    end
  end
  true
end

def sum_prime_2(number)
  i = 0
  prime = 1
  output = [2]
  while prime < number
    if prime?(prime, output)
      i += 1
      output << prime if prime != 1
    end 
    prime += 2
  end
  output.inject(:+)
end
```

And here is what I've come up with, but it's not quite working. I'd love any help.

```
def sum_prime(number)
  i = 0
  prime = 1
  output = [2]
  while prime < number
    if output.each { |x| prime % x == 0 } == true # prime? method
      output << prime if prime != 1
      i += 1
    end 
    prime += 2
  end
  output.inject(:+)
end
```

Comment: What is the point of the two `output` lines, the first on a single line immediately after `while prime < number` and again after `i += 1`?

Comment: How is this different from the last time[1] you asked this question?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365382/speed-up-array-functions-in-ruby/20366298#20366298

Comment: @Tin Thanks for catching that. I was using them to see what was going on, but I removed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplification of your current approach:

```
def sum_primes(limit)
  primes = [2]
  n = 3
  while n < limit
    primes << n if primes.all? { |p| n % p != 0 }
    n += 2
  end
  primes.inject(:+)
end
```

But you can do better. For example, there's no need to check for divisibility by all prior primes -- only up to the square of `n`. Even better would be a [sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) approach, particularly an incremental one.

Comment: I just did a quick benchmark test, and this version is actually 30% slower than the original!

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I had forgotten about using all? with the block. I realize that there are faster ways to do this, but I was particularly interested in combining them an you answered just that. Thank you very much.

Comment: And limit is a much better variable name than number. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use this code, rather than combining the two functions:

```
def prime?(number, array)
  array.each do |x|
    if number % x == 0
      return false
    end
    return true if x * x > number
  end
  true
end
```

Doing a quick benchmark for `sum_prime_2(100000)` versus `FMc`'s answer versus mine, the original code takes about 5.0 seconds, `FMc`'s takes 6.5 seconds, but my version just 0.1 seconds.

Comment: It's a somewhat irrelevant to benchmark the original code, your code, or my modification of the OP's attempted approach -- because they are all terrible algorithms. Sort of like a tortoise race at the zoo. Checking for primeness by brute-force divisibility is not the way to go if we really care about large N.